# I'm making a 7 Little Words game, and trying to split each word into two- and three-letter segments

Tags: java, android

If you haven't played 7 Little Words, you can find it at 7littlewords.com. I'm trying to make a game similar to this, except using a list of SAT vocab words, for Android. I've coded the entire thing, but the actual splitting part is throwing me an error. Here's my code for that section:

```
for (String word : allWords){
            int index = 0;   //placeholder var for next part
            int ntwos = 0;   //number of two letter tiles this word will have
            int nthrees = 0; //number of three letter tiles this word will have
            ArrayList<String> splitList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                if((word.length()-(i*2)) % 3 == 0){
                    ntwos = i;
                    break; //we just brute forced a number of twos and threes that works 
                }
            }

            nthrees = (word.length()-(2*ntwos))/3;
            int total = ntwos + nthrees;
            while (total > 0){
                if ((int)(Math.random()*2)==0 && ntwos > 0){
                    ntwos--;
                    splitList.add(word.substring(index,index+2));
                    index += 2;
                    total--;
                } else if (nthrees > 0) {
                    nthrees--;
                    splitList.add(word.substring(index,index+3));
                    index += 3;
                    total--;
                } else {
                    ntwos--;
                    splitList.add(word.substring(index,index+2));
                    index += 2;
                    total--;
                }                   
            }

            splitMap.put(word,splitList);
        }
```

This is contained within a method, of course. What's throwing the actual error is the line:

```
splitList.add(word.substring(index,index+2));
```

which is throwing me an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Anyone got any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: Looks like `index+2` is greater than `word.length`.

Comment: why are you subtracting the length of variable word with the index?
                if((word.length()-(i*2)) % 3 == 0){

Comment: @Sara I am trying to find a number of twos and threes that works. i represents the number of twos in the word. For example, if i=2 and word.length()=7, then 7-2(2)%3 = 0. Therefore, if you have a seven-letter word, then you can have two twos.

Comment: it seems like you want to achieve having the maximum number of twos in the word? why do it with a loop. can you just not decide that if the word length % 2 == 0, then notwos = wordlength / 2. otherwise notwos = wordlength-3 / 2